# Are there open source CAPTCHA solutions available?

Tags: language-agnostic, validation, captcha

I'm in the process of adding CAPTCHA validation to one of my websites and need to know what open source solutions exist.  Please note strengths and weaknesses and what platform they work with.  I'm primarily interested in ASP.NET solutions but feel free to include PHP, Java, etc.

Comment: thing is CAPTCHA is opensource... reCAPCHA is a service runned by google... you have almost no say in the graphic design of the service, even if it absolutely obtuse to your site design...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[ReCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/whyrecaptcha.html) is the same one StackOverflow uses. It has an [ASP.NET implementation](http://recaptcha.net/plugins/aspnet/).

It uses a webservice to provide the captcha images; this is an university trying to digitize difficult to OCR texts. I'm not sure how easy it would be to replace this portion. There are many [open source client implementations](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/), as the API is [quite well documented](http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html).

Comment: Has anyone ever found eny resources on how hard it is to crack (by OCR or other attempts) the captchas provided by ReCAPTCHA?

Comment: ReCAPTCHA is owned by google now. Using it helps google to digitize books, and also now to build their geo address database from housenumbers in streetview photos. All of this is undeniably clever, but this may not be well aligned with the goals of some projects ...and it's not open source

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood has a captcha control + source hosted on his [coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000094.html) site

[ReCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) might be another alternative but i don't think the source is open.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [JCaptcha](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/)? Not an ASP framework, but might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one... http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/CaptchaImage.asp very nice article!

Answer (score 1):

In the Java world, check out [JCaptcha](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

One I just found but have not tried out is [MyCaptcha](http://mycaptcha.codeplex.com/releases/view/34719)

Answer (score 1):

ReCaptcha has many benefits.  The fact that google owns it is a big plus.  We used to use ReCaptcha on my project, but the firewall in our production environment cannot handle add entries based on domain name, only based on IP addresses.  ReCaptcha has switched to using Googles infrastructure, so the IP addresses are no longer publicly available.  Our production environment is locked down extremely tightly, so there are no workarounds possible -- we have to start using a  new captcha.  If you're in my boat, ReCaptcha won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [ReCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/)?